# Response.Redirect doesn't work in login page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

when trying to access a search function button in my site master page while in the login page, the page just gets refreshed, using Server.Transfer instead throws the "Error executing child request for " error, accessing from everywhere else is okay, could this be I can't get out of the 'secure zone' while in the login page? Does this has anything to do with the web.config, I am not sure which portion of code should I look into either.

Please kindly advice. Thanks.

This is click event:

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TextBox1.Text != "")
            {
                Session["txtValue"] = TextBox1.Text;
                Response.Redirect("ProductSearch.aspx");
            }
        }
```

Comment: this is somewhat difficult to follow based on this. Can you revise a little and make it clearer? For instance - mypage.aspx button, is this a linkbutton, a regular link, a regular button, what? What is the specific error you get?

Comment: Hi, I have tried both linkbutton and regular button, this is my click event: 
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TextBox1.Text != "")
            {
                Session["txtValue"] = TextBox1.Text;
                Response.Redirect("ProductSearch.aspx");
            }
        }

Comment: are you sure that the  button1_click is called?

Comment: Yes, accessing outside of the login page works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your login page should not use the site master page. (Nor should any error pages). In that way, the various code you run in the master page will not need to run in the unauthorized context.

The web.config will always send the requests back to the login page if the user is unauthorized.  If your code does run, you can find loops leading to stack overflows.

Answer (score 0):

Is the page you're trying to navigate to (ProductSearch.aspx) protected (i.e. do you need to first login to access it)? If so, and if you are not yet logged in then any attempt to navigate to ProductSearch.aspx would automatically redirect you back to the login page (as you describe).

Cheers, Wayne.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would make sure there is nothing in your ProductSearch page that would redirect you, maybe based on your session state or something. Also check the master page to make sure its not that redirecting you. Finally, if its still not working, I'd use the debugger and just step through your code.